# kdm fails to start after update (debian testing)

Tags: debian, kde, testing, kdm

I just updated debian (testing). I use kde and after updating, kdm does not start.... I end up on the CLI. If I check the status of kdm with systemctl, it says it's **started (existed)** but it didn't even blink.

```
Starting LSB: X Display manager for KDE...
Started LSB: X Display manager for KDE.
```

I see nothing funny on `journalctl -f` when I try to run `systenctl start kdm` or `systemctl restart kdm`... all in all, I don't know what to check to get logs off it. Other than that, I am able to go into xfce by running `startx` so at least I know that X is working properly.

Question: what can I do to find out what's going on with kdm?

I think I have the first clue. kdm package is gone from debian testing? What is being used for it instead?

Comment: Use `sddm` instead. It's the official display manager for plasma

Answer (score 3):

Yes, kdm is gone. It was a part of KDE4 and previous versions. You may already have [sddm](https://packages.debian.org/buster/sddm) on your system, which is the most common replacement, and is recommended by kde-plasma-desktop; if not, you can install it or another package providing `x-display-manager`, e.g. lightdm or lxdm.

Answer (score 2):

The list of [available X display](https://wiki.debian.org/DisplayManager#Available_X_display_managers) managers.

For `kde` the default display manager is `sddm` but you can use the others too.